# Django request flow

Tags: django

I'm trying to understand the Django request processing.

My goal is to redirect a user immediately after he has signed in but when I run this code, I see that my database has not been populated with the entry I want to and the redirect throws a `DoesNotExist` exception.

When I replace `HttpResponseRedirect()` with a `HttpResponse()` the same code works.

Either I am missing some piece of code or Django is considering the redirect a part of the earlier request and doing the redirect but not the update.

Has anybody faced this issue before?

**Django version - 1.4**

**Signup view** (not updating database) -

```
try:
    email_id = request.GET.__getitem__('email_id')
    name = request.GET.__getitem__('name')
    try:
        Person.objects.create(email_id=email_id, name=name)
        request.session['email_id'] = email_id
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/myaccount/')
    except IntegrityError:
        return render_to_response('signup.html')
except MultiValueDictKeyError:
    return render_to_response('signup.html')
```

**Signup view** (updating database correctly) -

```
try:
    email_id = request.GET.__getitem__('email_id')
    name = request.GET.__getitem__('name')
    try:
        Person.objects.create(email_id=email_id, name=name)
        request.session['email_id'] = email_id
        return HttpResponse('This Works!!')
    except IntegrityError:
        return render_to_response('signup.html')
except MultiValueDictKeyError:
    return render_to_response('signup.html')
```

**Myaccount view** -

```
# Custom function that decodes the email_id from the session
email_id = return_email_id(request)
user = Person.objects.get(email_id=email_id)
name = user.name
return render_to_response('myaccount.html', {'name': name})
```

EDIT:

Code for return_email_id():

```
def return_email_id(request): 
    try:
        check_session(request)
        session_cookie = request.COOKIES['sessionid']
        session_object = Session.objects.get(pk=session_cookie)
        get_email_id = session_object.get_decoded()['email_id']
        return HttpResponse(get_email_id)
    except PermissionDenied:
        raise PermissionDenied()

    def check_session(request):
        if request.session.get('email_id'):
            return True
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied()
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, please stop using double-underscore methods like `__getitem__`. There is almost never a good reason to do so, and certainly not one in the code you have posted. GET is a dict-like object, so please use the `get()` method.

Comment: And the problem appears to be related to your `return_email_id` function, perhaps you should post the code for that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Thanks. I will change `__getitem__` to use `get()`.

Comment: There's also `get_or_create`, which appears to more "Django-nic" to use than a `try`-`except IntegretyError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem determined to do things the hard way.

Your `return_email_id` function is doing a lot of unnecessary work. The session is available directly in `request.session`, so there is no point getting the cookie, querying the session store, decoding it, etc.

The actual problem is probably that you are returning an HttpResponse from that function, whereas the view is actually expecting an email which it can use to query the Person model. But I would get rid of the whole function, and just do the simplest thing in the view:

```
email_id = request.session.get('email_id')
if email_id:
    user = Person.objects.get(email_id=email_id)
    name = user.name
    return render_to_response('myaccount.html', {'name': name})
else:
    # return something else if email doesn't exist
```

(although you should probably also deal with the case that the Person call raises a DoesNotExist exception because there is no matching email in the db).

Comment: I totally missed that I had put the HttpResponse return there for testing and forgot to remove it. Also the true purpose of having the decoding is to get the session'ed user's email ID while making the DB request (the email ID being a primary key). On a separate note, would it make sense for me to set a cookie with the customer ID and use that for processing DB requests? Probably I have a bad DB design.

Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes but my point is you shouldn't query the SessionStore directly, you should get it from `request.session` which is the supported API. And no, this is precisely what the session is for so you shouldn't use a separate cookie.

Comment: Perfect. I see what I was doing now. I was under the impression that `request.session` had all the values of all the sessions. You have been super helpful - much thanks.